# Issue with displaying image from firebase snapshot url

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uiimageview

I am trying to display an image from a url stored in the firebase database in a UIImageView. The path returns the proper url(I can see it in the console); however, the image doesn't appear in the connected image view. Any suggestions?

```
let imgRef = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://ryan-915d2.firebaseio.com/")
        imgRef.child("locations")
              .child("111 Smith Street")
              .child("building ")
              .child("image")
              .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            if let url = snapshot.value as? String {
                print(snapshot, "I found the image")
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
                    if error == nil {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.imageView.image = image
                        }
                    }
                }.resume()
        }
     }
  )}
```

}

Comment: checked if there is an error inside URLSession

Comment: @Sh_Khan No error